# Group by single column in Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table like below: I need to display it as without duplicates. So I need to groupby customer alone. c1 has both 'Name'

```
Id  Name    customer
1   XXXX     c1
2   YYYY     c1
```

I need to get the values on c1 : xxx ,yyy. But its getting c1: xxx and c1: yyy.
My code is:

```
public List<data> GetComponentStatus()
{
    List<data> d= null;
    using(var entity=new FM())
    {
         d = entity.getdata()
             .Select(
                a => new data
                {
                    Customer = a.id,
                    Name = a.name,
                })
            .GroupBy(a=>a.Customer).Select(a=>a.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
    }
    return d;
}
```

From this, I am getting the first record or last record when using LastorDefault().

I want to get both 'Name' on single Customer C1.

Comment: `Customer = a.id,` should be `Customer = a.customer` for starters. Then you need to select after the groupby : `Select(g => new { Customer = g.Key, Names = g.Select(gg => gg.Name) })`

Comment: omit fistordefault().. just take toList() after groupby

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to group by `Customer` and get `Name` as comma seperated. I created sample data of yours and wrote LINQ in query syntax. See the demo output on rextester below.

```
var data = new[] { new {ID = 1,Name = "XXXX", customer= "C1"},
                           new {ID = 2,Name = "YYYY", customer= "C1"},
                         };

        var query = from a in data
                    group a by a.customer into grp
                    select new {Cutomer= grp.Key ,Name = string.Join(",",grp.Select (g => g.Name)) };

        foreach (var e in query)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Customer: {0} ,Name: {1}", e.Cutomer,e.Name);
        }
```

Its Demo on [rextester](http://rextester.com/RWXJU19979)

So  your code should be like this

```
public List<data> GetComponentStatus()
    {

        using(var entity=new FM())
        {
            var  d =  from a in entity.getdata()
                      group a by a.customer into grp
                      select new data {Cutomer= grp.Key ,Name = string.Join(",",grp.Select (g => g.Name))};

                return d.ToList(); 
        }

    }
```